# monit removes quotes from start program commands

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-ec2, monit

I am debugging monit start/stop program statements. In my `/etc/monit.conf` file, my `start program` statement looks like this:

```
check process node with pidfile /home/ec2-user/blah/node.pid
    start program = "/bin/su -c 'export APP_ENV=development; /home/ec2-user/local/bin/node /home/ec2-user/example.com/current/api.js start &> /tmp/monit.out ' "
    stop program = "/bin/su -c '/home/ec2-user/local/bin/node /home/ec2-user/example.com/current/api.js stop'""
```

which I've tested in a shell with

```
$ sudo su
# env -i PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin /bin/sh
# /bin/su -c '/usr/bin/env APP_ENV=development; /home/ec2-user/local/bin/node /home/ec2-user/example.com/current/api.js start &> /tmp/monit.out '
```

running this returns in the `/tmp/monit.out` file the correct output:

```
Starting nodejs daemon...
nodejs daemon started. PID: 16408
```

But when I run `sudo monit -v monitor node`, it displays a **different command, identical except with the inner single quotes removed**:

```
The service list contains the following entries:

Process Name          = node
 Pid file             = /home/ec2-user/blah/node.pid
 Monitoring mode      = active
 Start program        = '/bin/su -c export APP_ENV=development; /home/ec2-user/local/bin/node /home/ec2-user/example.com/current/api.js start &> /tmp/monit.out ' timeout 30 second(s)
 Stop program         = '/bin/su -c /home/ec2-user/local/bin/node /home/ec2-user/example.com/current/api.js stop' timeout 30 second(s)
 Existence            = if does not exist 1 times within 1 cycle(s) then restart else if succeeded 1 times within 1 cycle(s) then alert
 Pid                  = if changed 1 times within 1 cycle(s) then alert
 Ppid                 = if changed 1 times within 1 cycle(s) then alert

System Name           = system_ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.ec2.internal
 Monitoring mode      = active
```

I can't find anything about this in the monit documentation. The documentation [here](http://www.mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/FAQ#execution) seems to be the ultimate reference but short of going through the source code, I'm not sure what to do next.

My command works perfectly without the quotes removed, so I just need to fix this issue. All ideas and possible fixes welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a quite late answer, nevertheless I find it important since it causes some misunderstanding (so I was misleaded)

You don't need to escape a single quote character. Try it:

```
check process fake_proc
  with pidfile /tmp/test_pid
  start = "/bin/bash -c 'echo $$ > /tmp/test_pid'"
  stop = "echo stop > /tmp/test_pid"
```

It will not shown as a started process, however `test_pid` file is created. Add `; sleep xx` to catch a process and examine its properties.

The problem might be caused by a some env-specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Put the commands regarding the "start program" and "stop program" into a shell script, make it executable and then give its address to monit.

also, try to escape it single quote using slash

> \'

(i haven't tried so i don't know if it works).